# How to reference Windows.Storage from a Uno class library

Tags: uwp, uno-platform

I'm trying to port a UWP class library to Uno Platfrom but I cannot figure out what references I need in the `.csproj` file to resolve System.Windows types.

I'm seeing:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

The few samples I've found that reference `Windows.Storage` don't appear to need anything other than `Uno.Core`.

I've tried adding `<PackageReference Include="Uno.Core" Version="2.3.0" />` to the `.csproj` file but it doesn't resolve the problem.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Windows.Storage` namespace is part of the UWP API surface which Uno implements on non-Windows targets. It is part of the `Uno.UI` NuGet package, so you need to reference it to be able to use it.

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create your class library using the **Cross-Platform  Library (Uno Platform) template** which you will find in the New Project dialog after installing Uno Platform extension in Visual Studio. Such a class library already contains on the necessary configuration a multi-targeted library needs, including the reference to Uno.UI.

[image: Uno Platform Cross-Platform Library template in New Project dialog]